# 0x80131700 Build Error on .NET Micro Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-micro-framework

The following build error occurs when using .NET Micro Framework project, whether in emulator mode or not.

```
0x80131700
```

or

```
error MMP0000: 0x80131700
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution by way of a drop-in file [available on CodePlex (click here)](http://netmf.codeplex.com/workitem/221), also contains suggestions about frameworks.**

*Note: Ran into this problem during an electronics class, Googled the above answer, posting solution here for people to find, for archive and easy future reference.*

---

**Description**
MetaDataProcessor fails with the above error during the build of .NET Micro Framework project on a computer where only .NET Framework 4.0 is installed (e.g. Visual Studio 2010 on a clean Windows XP Mode virtual machine). To workaround the issue copy the attached **MetaDataProcessor.exe.config** file into a directory where the .exe file is located (default %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft .NET Micro Framework\v4.1\Tools); alternatively install .NET Framework 2.0+ (3.5 SP1).

**File Attachment** - MetaDataProcessor.exe.config contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration>     
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">         
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>    
    </startup>  
</configuration>
```